# Failed to push some refs on github

Tags: git, github

I have been trying to push my coding projects onto github but I keep getting the error "refspec master does not match any" and "failed to push some refs to GITHUB URL".

I have simply been following the steps outlined on the Github website.

I did the following (in this order) after setting the current directory to my projects folder:

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "First commit"
$ git remote add origin GITHUBREPOURL
$ git remote -v
$ git push origin master
```

After this last command, I get the above error. I have been looking up reasons why it could be happening but the ones I have found don't seem to be working. I have tried

```
$ git push -f origin master
```

and still get the same error. My current folder also becomes the master when I init, so I am really confused.

Edit: When I $ git branch, I get the error "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git".

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: what is the output of `git branch`? Can you add it to the original question?

Comment: Yes, I get an error which I show in the edit.

Comment: `git push -u origin master` is work?

Comment: Well..... you are not working inside a git repo... which is funny given that you ran `git init`. Were you able to add/commit without issues? If you did without issues, are you going into another directory after committing but before pushing?

Comment: @pwxcoo I still get the same error.

Comment: @eftshift0 When I add, I get a bunch of warnings about LF will be replaced by CRLF. When I commit, it says "Please tell me who you are" and also "fatal: unable to auto-detect email address". Could these be suggesting the problem? My directory remains the same so I doubt that's a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are getting errors in the process and assuming that your commands were successful... which, apparently, they were not. You need to configure your name and mail.... for starters [1]. Then you should at least be able to commit.

The problem is that, because you haven't committed yet on a fresh new repo, there's actually no revision that could be pushed.

[1] https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-your-dvcs-username-for-commits-950301867.html

PS The conversion between CRLF and LF is a whole different can of worms. Consider asking git *not* no mess with CTRL/LF conversions. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes Look for the **text** property.

Comment: Yep, that worked! How silly of me. Thanks for the help! I no longer get the CRLF and LF stuff either. So that got fixed too with the email stuff.